Unrecognized function or variable 'x' in MATLAB solving system of nonlinear equations
I keep getting error Unrecognized function or variable 'x' while running this code.
function aby = system_of_eqs(x)
    % a=alpha, b=beta, y=gamma
    % Initialize aby as a vector of zeros
    aby = zeros(3, 1);

    % First equation
    aby(1) = ( ((1/x(1)) + (1/x(2)) + (1/x(3))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(2*x(2))) + (1/(4*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(3*x(2))) + (1/(9*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(4*x(2))) + (1/(16*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(5*x(2))) + (1/(25*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(6*x(2))) + (1/(36*x(3)))));

    % Second equation
    aby(2) = ( ((1/x(1)) + (1/x(2)) + (1/x(3))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(2*x(2))) + (1/(4*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(3*x(2))) + (1/(9*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(4*x(2))) + (1/(16*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(5*x(2))) + (1/(25*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(6*x(2))) + (1/(36*x(3)))));

    % Third equation
    aby(3) = ( ((1/x(1)) + (1/x(2)) + (1/x(3))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(2*x(2))) + (1/(4*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(3*x(2))) + (1/(9*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(4*x(2))) + (1/(16*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(5*x(2))) + (1/(25*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) + 
    (1/(6*x(2))) + (1/(36*x(3)))));

    % Use a non-zero initial guess
    x0 = [1, 4, 19]; % Non-zero initial guess

    % Solve the system of equations using fsolve
    solution = fsolve(@system_of_eqs, x0);

    % Display the solution
    display(solution)
end

matlab code (2023b)
I have even defined x before the function as a number but still get the same error. This makes no sense to me. How am I supposed to solve for x1, x2, x3 which is the whole point?

How do you "run this code"? It's a function, you must call it. x is defined in that call.

It looks like the part that starts with x0 = [1, 4, 19] to the end is the script that uses the function system_of_eqs(). This part should be written outside the function, not inside it! Put it at the top of the file, with the function definition at the bottom.

You have written a recursive function that crashes.
The name of the function system_of_eqs is used inside fsove as the function to use to run fsolve inside system_of_eqs.
To run system_of_eqs you have to input x that we the readers do not see because you have not supplied the code calling system_of_eqs but let's assume that you did all correctly to invoke system_of_eqs
x=[1 2 3]
system_of_eqs(x)

now once inside system_of_eqs upon reaching fsolve ,  as you have defined system_of_eqs this function requires the input field x to be defined.
MATLAB cannot proceed to solve with fsolve in the way system_of_eqs is currently defined.
You have to either define the function to be used by fsolve with another name or far better; define the function without the fsolve inside.
1.-
Define system_of_eqs ike this
function y=system_of_eqs(x)

    % First equation
    y(1) = ( ((1/x(1)) + (1/x(2)) + (1/x(3))) + ((1/x(1)) +   (1/(2*x(2))) + (1/(4*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(3*x(2))) + (1/(9*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) +     (1/(4*x(2))) + (1/(16*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(5*x(2))) + (1/(25*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) +     (1/(6*x(2))) + (1/(36*x(3)))));

    % Second equation
    y(2) = ( ((1/x(1)) + (1/x(2)) + (1/x(3))) + ((1/x(1)) +     (1/(2*x(2))) + (1/(4*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(3*x(2))) + (1/(9*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) +     (1/(4*x(2))) + (1/(16*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(5*x(2))) + (1/(25*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) +     (1/(6*x(2))) + (1/(36*x(3)))));

    % Third equation
    y(3) = ( ((1/x(1)) + (1/x(2)) + (1/x(3))) + ((1/x(1)) +     (1/(2*x(2))) + (1/(4*x(3)))) + ...
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(3*x(2))) + (1/(9*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) +     (1/(4*x(2))) + (1/(16*x(3)))) + ... 
    ((1/x(1)) + (1/(5*x(2))) + (1/(25*x(3)))) + ((1/x(1)) +     (1/(6*x(2))) + (1/(36*x(3)))));

2.-
Solve with fsolve using correct syntax
x0=[1 2 3]
f1=@system_of_eqs
fsolve(f1,x0)

=
   1.0e+02 *
   6.298874874335936   4.673058950322499   3.960434817680791

Same result is obtained with the x0 = [1 4 19] defined in question
3.- fsolve produces the additional note
No solution found.

**fsolve stopped because the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient,
but the vector of function values is not near zero as measured by the
value of the function tolerance.**

with
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');
y2=fsolve(f1,x0,options)

                                         Norm of      First-order   Trust-region
 Iteration  Func-count     f(x)          step         optimality    radius
     0          4         134.308                           120               1
     1          8         40.7951              1           16.6               1
     2         12         21.4812              1           5.37               1
     3         16         13.9187              1           2.46               1
     4         20         9.98199              1           1.36               1
     5         24         7.59035              1          0.843               1
     6         28         6.00003              1          0.566               1
     7         32         4.87936              1          0.401               1
     8         36         4.05639              1          0.296               1
     9         40         2.74514            2.5          0.156             2.5
    10         44         1.99759            2.5         0.0936             2.5
    11         48         1.52864            2.5         0.0607             2.5
    12         52         1.21364            2.5         0.0418             2.5
    13         56        0.990841            2.5         0.0301             2.5
    14         60        0.650616           6.25         0.0152            6.25
    15         64        0.463832           6.25        0.00878            6.25
    16         68        0.348728           6.25        0.00557            6.25
    17         72        0.272192           6.25        0.00377            6.25
    18         76        0.218515           6.25        0.00268            6.25
    19         80        0.137793         15.625        0.00132            15.6
    20         84       0.0947877         15.625       0.000747            15.6
    21         88       0.0691766         15.625       0.000464            15.6
    22         92       0.0527003         15.625       0.000308            15.6
    23         96       0.0414793         15.625       0.000215            15.6
    24        100       0.0334948         15.625       0.000156            15.6
    25        104       0.0213184        39.0625       7.92e-05            39.1
    26        108       0.0147501        39.0625       4.55e-05            39.1
    27        112       0.0108084        39.0625       2.86e-05            39.1
    28        116      0.00825892        39.0625       1.91e-05            39.1
    29        120       0.0065156        39.0625       1.34e-05            39.1
    30        124       0.0052712        39.0625       9.73e-06            39.1
    31        128      0.00336616        97.6563       4.96e-06            97.7
    32        132       0.0023342        97.6562       2.87e-06            97.7
    33        136      0.00171313        97.6562        1.8e-06            97.7
    34        140      0.00131059        97.6562       1.21e-06            97.7
    35        144       0.0010349        97.6562       8.46e-07            97.7

Let's change method
options = optimoptions('linprog','Algorithm','dual-simplex','Display','off');
y2=fsolve(f1,x0,options)


Warning: You have passed LINPROG options to FSOLVE. FSOLVE will use the
common options and ignore the LINPROG options that do not apply.
To avoid this warning, convert the LINPROG options using OPTIMOPTIONS. 
 In optim.options/SolverOptions/convertForSolver (line 776)
In prepareOptionsForSolver (line 49)
In fsolve (line 174) 

y2 =
   1.0e+03 *
   1.398666270065036   1.037653551559435   0.879415418789467

now fsolve still solving yet issuing more warnings.
With yet another different method
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt');
[y3,fval,exitflag] = fsolve(f1,x0,options);

y3 =
   1.0e+03 *
   2.733060678987443   2.026813806848032   1.716724478563590

Now there are no more warnings or notes.
Yet it's been seen that changing x0 different results are obtained.
